# Is this safe? Sandwiched 2x2s taking weight of ceiling

Tags: joists, brick, load

We’ve started doing some work on our stairway, where we need to replace the 2x6 with 2 2x7s because we are making the clearance bigger.

We’ve noticed that the current 2x6 joist parallel with the staircase, which has joist hangers holding 2x6 joists which is the dining room ceiling, seems to be sitting on 2 2x2s sandwiched together, where they are nailed to a 3x9. The 3x9 and the 2 2x2s are sitting on the external wall of the house. The 2 2x2s continue on further on the other side, where they go to, I don’t know, hence in the picture they are cut off the same place as the 3x9, but the 2 2x2s do continue on under the stairs somewhere. Whether they rest on a wall or stud or something on the other end I don’t know.

Question is, can you do this? Can you use 2 2x2s sandwiched and mailed to a 3x9 to support the weight of a 2x6 ceiling? It doesn’t seem right…

I’ve shown how the 2x6 parallel to the stairs has been notched so that it seems on the 2 2x2s.

Sorry for the bad drawing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: From your sketch, I couldn't tell why there are 2 2x2 attached to the 3x9, but if there are 2x6s spaced nearby, I can assure you the 2x2s has no structural function but could be there for closure purpose. Can you take a photo of this area from underneath?

Comment: Hey, I can’t take a picture underneath it cos there’s a brick wall, but I’ve taken a picture of the 2x6 staircase joist, the 3x9 at the back, with the 2 2x2s beneath it. See updated

Comment: It is non-structural, however, the ceiling could have attached to the underside of the 2x2. If you can open the other side, the purpose could become clear.

Comment: Either way, surely the weight of a ceiling cannot be relied on 2 2x2s purely being nailed toe nailed to a 3x9?? The 2x6 joist resting on the 2 2x2s (perpendicular to the dining room ceiling joists) is also toe nailed in to the 3x9, but surely that’s not enough to hold anything?

Comment: Yes, it looks odd. I am afraid that more structural detail is required to fully understand the purpose of the 2x2s.